# jQuery wScratchPad: Responsive Design?

Tags: android, jquery, css, mobile, android-canvas

I have added the wScratchPad to a website project. And it's working.

But the project is based on responsive design. That means the size of all elements adapt to the screen size, so it's optimized for mobile devices too.

The situation is that the size of the scratch-area remains the same, no matter how small you make the browser-window.

```
<div id="wScratchPad"></div>    
<script type="text/javascript">
        var scratch = function(e, percent){
            if ( percent > 50 ) {
                sp.wScratchPad('clear');
            }
        }

        var sp = $("#wScratchPad").wScratchPad({
            width           : 363,
            height          : 117,
            realtimePercent : true,
            scratchDown: scratch,
            scratchMove: scratch,
            cursor:'./cursors/coin.png',
            scratchUp: scratch,
            image: './images/1.png',
            image2: './images/2.png'
        });
    </script>
```

The "width" and "height" are needed to calculate the overlaying canvas and the pixels for uncovering the background-image.

Is there any way to let the scratch area size adapt to the window-size?

Answer (score 0):

One solution you could try would be to set the scratchpad's dimensions to be a percentage of the dimensions of the browser viewport, using `document.documentElement.clientWidth`/`clientHeight`. For example:

```
var sp = $("#wScratchPad").wScratchPad({
    width           : document.documentElement.clientWidth / 4,
    height          : document.documentElement.clientHeight / 4,
    ...
    });
```